# Linux pgrep active xsession

Tags: bash, session, ubuntu, process, while-loop

I'm writing a code which :

1. put all xsessions name in a file.
2. while not EOF , assign a line to a
       variable, then pass it to pgrep, line by line.
3. Output pgrep in terminal.

There is several way to print the desktop environnement,session/window manager.

But i couldn't find one wich work for all xsession(/usr/share/xsessions).

After many try , it still doesn't work.
There is a problem with the loop.

`ls /usr/share/xsessions/>all_xsessions;while [ "$var" != "" ]; do let x=x+1; var=$(sed "${x}q;d" all_xsessions); pgrep -lu $(whoami) $var; done`

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? Do you want to find all running x-sessions for current user? Their names or their PID's?

Comment: The current running session , the name and PID . In one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no real standart way or universal environmental variable for that.
Most of information can be get from `printenv` but variable names differ a lot.

For example, in arch-linux with xfce, where sessions are run directly from windows-manager, you can get **PID** from `$SESSION_MANAGER` variable.

But in ubuntu, that is the most popular desktop distro now, your x-session is in fact upstart-session, that starts everything needed. And the variable is `$UPSTART_SESSION`.

And in xubuntu you have BOTH $SESSION_MANAGER and $UPSTART_SESSION variables.

There is also `$DESKTOP_SESSION`, it exists almost everywhere and contains some pretty name for desktop-environment, like xfce, ubuntu of xubuntu.

So, that can differ from distro to distro, but in most cases that script will work for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -n $SESSION_MANAGER ]] && pid="${SESSION_MANAGER##*/}"
[[ -n $UPSTART_SESSION ]] && pid="${UPSTART_SESSION##*/}"
process_name=$(cat /proc/$pid/cmdline)
pretty_name=$DESKTOP_SESSION

echo "$process_name : $pid : $pretty_name"
```

And output will be like that:

```
# Arch with xfce
xfce4-session : 3021 : xfce
# Ubuntu
/sbin/upstart--user : 3153 : ubuntu
# Xubuntu
init--user : 2343 : xubuntu
```

**EDIT**: Your method can work in some cases, but most of the time it will fail. Just because right now on ubuntu I have:

```
$ ls -1 /usr/share/xsessions/
openbox.desktop
ubuntu.desktop
```

And x-session starting process in Unity looks like that:

```
root       964  0.0  0.0 276680  6032 ?        SLsl 00:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
root       997  3.8  0.9 255676 74708 tty7     Ss+  00:16   0:15  \_ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
root      1196  0.0  0.0 230304  6420 ?        Sl   00:16   0:00  \_ lightdm --session-child 12 19
user      1442  0.0  0.0  53756  4924 ?        Ss   00:16   0:00      \_ /sbin/upstart --user
user      1734  0.0  0.0  39992   280 ?        S    00:16   0:00          \_ upstart-udev-bridge --daemon --user
user      1737  0.2  0.0  43932  4332 ?        Ss   00:16   0:00          \_ dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-wkfpguwfxw
user      1749  0.0  0.1  93416  8756 ?        Ss   00:16   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/window-stack-bridge
```

So there is no correlation between name of session in `/usr/share/xsessions/` and real process `cmdline`. So pgrep won't find anything in that cases.

Comment: thans , but what do you think of my method ?

Comment: thanks , but what do you think of my method ? I would like to understand how to correct my code.

Comment: @infinite Unfortunately, it won't work most of the time. Edited the answer to explain.